# How to use schema-h2.sql

Tags: spring-boot

Spring Boot 2.4.3.

schema-h2.sql seems to have no effect.

The H2 database is created, but no tables are created.

schema-h2.sql:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Blogger;

CREATE TABLE Blogger(
id bigint NOT NULL,
name varchar(100),
age int,
PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Story;

CREATE TABLE Story(
id bigint NOT NULL,
title varchar(100),
content varchar(400),
posted date,
blogger_id int,
PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

application.properties:

```
spring.thymeleaf.cache=false
spring.web.locale-resolver=fixed
spring.web.locale=en
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/db
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
```

Any advice?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution, I need to add **spring.datasource.platform=h2** property